# Highcharts: TreeMap Select State not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

http://jsfiddle.net/sgrg93/7z6r4gkk/

```
plotOptions: {
  treemap: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    states: {
      hover: {
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

In the above code, I've used **hover** state which enables me to see red colored borders when I hover on them. Also when I **select** multiple tree-sections, the red colored borders are maintained.

Now what I require is that only when I **select** tree-sections, red colored borders are seen, and on **hover**, no change of borders is observed.

Something like this (which is not working)

```
plotOptions: {
  treemap: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    states: {
      select: {     //hover changed to select
        borderColor: "red"  //change color only on select and not on hover
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your treemap sections have red borders only when selected, and not on the hover state, try the following:

```
plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
            events: {
                select: function () {
                    this.update({
                        borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 4
                    });                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you're doing here is setting a `select` event for your point (the item in the treemap you want your users to select) and then asking it to update the border color and width (I added the width just to better illustrate the change).

Here's a modified fiddle you can review: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/7z6r4gkk/5/

I hope this is helpful for you!

Comment: ...and on [`unselect` event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.treemap.point.events.unselect) you can revert the changes - http://jsfiddle.net/7z6r4gkk/6/